# Regex for floor in address

Tags: java, regex

I have this regex:

```
String regexPattern = "[0-9A-Za-z]+(st|nd|rd|th)" + " " + "floor";
```

I want to test it against:

```
String lineString = "8th floor, Prince's Building, 12 Chater Road";
```

so I do:

```
boolean isMatching = lineString.matches(regexPattern);
```

and it return false. Why?

I thought it had something to do with whitespaces in Java, so I removed the whitespace in the regexPattern variable so it reads

```
regexPattern = "[0-9A-Za-z]+(st|nd|rd|th)floor";
```

and matched it with a string without white space:

```
String lineString = "8thfloor,Prince'sBuilding,12ChaterRoad"
```

it still returns false. Why? Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) only returns `true` if the *entire* string matches the pattern.

Try adding `.*` to the beginning and end of your regex.

Example:

```
String regex = ".*[0-9A-Za-z]+(st|nd|rd|th)" + " " + "floor.*";
```

This is not the best approach, however...

---

Here's a better alternative:

```
String input = "8th floor, Prince's Building, 12 Chater Road";
String regex = "[0-9A-Za-z]+(st|nd|rd|th)" + " " + "floor";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
boolean isMatch = p.matcher(input).find();
```

---

If you want to extract the floor number, do this:

```
String input = "8th floor, Prince's Building, 12 Chater Road";
String regex = "([0-9A-Za-z])+(st|nd|rd|th)" + " " + "floor";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    String num = m.group(1);
    String suffix = m.group(2);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the " + num + suffix + " floor!");
    // prints 'Welcome to the 8th floor!'
}
```

Check out the [Pattern API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for a boatload of info about Java regular expressions.

Comment: You're welcome.  The 2nd and 3rd approaches look less clean, but they're actually better.  For the best performance (if performance is an issue) make sure you compile the regex one time and reuse the `Pattern` object.  Compiling the regex is the most expensive operation (not matching it).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will try using the Pattern object.

Answer (score -1):

Edited, per comments ...

The `[0-9A-Za-z]+` part is greedily matching until the end of `th`.

Try `[0-9]` instead.